# How to create an APK for an Icon Pack?

Tags: android, icons, apk, android-launcher

I have created an Icon Pack for Android devices that run custom launchers, although I'm having trouble finding how to package them, so the launcher will recognize the icon pack. I know that it should be created into an APK, although I'm not sure on how to so this, or if there should be a certain format.

My question is, how do I create an APK, and if anyone knows, what format should it be presented in, so the launcher(such as Nova Launcher, or Apex Launcher.) will recognize the theme. 
If anyone can help, or has a link that can help me out, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> When you have tested it thouroughly and want to make it an app, Select File>Export>Export Android Application and Select your IconProject.
>
> Click on next and choose Create New Keystore and choose the location where you want it to be created. Enter any password you want.
> Click next, now, enter any name you want in alias, password, set Validity to 25 years(your choice), First and Last Names. Other Fields are Optional.

[[Guide]How to create icon packs - xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2399426)